# grep -o multiple occurrences of variable string in same line

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have the following line of text in a file:

`(http://onsnetwork.org/kubu4/2018/10/16/qpcr-c-gigas-primer-and-gdna-tests-with-18s-and-ef1-primers/), I checked Ronit's [DNased ctenidia RNA (from 20181016)](http://onsnetwork.org/kubu4/2018/10/16/dnase-treatment-ronits-c-gigas-ploiyddessication-ctenidia-rna/)`

I would like to extract each of the strings that match this pattern:

`(http://onsnetwork.org/kubu4/.*/)`

I've tried the following command, but it returns the entire line, despite the `-o` flag:

`grep -o "(http://onsnetwork.org/kubu4/.*/)" file.txt`

The output I'd like is this:

```
(http://onsnetwork.org/kubu4/2018/10/16/qpcr-c-gigas-primer-and-gdna-tests-with-18s-and-ef1-primers/)
(http://onsnetwork.org/kubu4/2018/10/16/dnase-treatment-ronits-c-gigas-ploiyddessication-ctenidia-rna/)
```

I'll be applying the `grep` command to a series of files that will have different text after `(http://onsnetwork.org/kubu4/`, so the command needs to allow for that flexibility.

I'm just not sure why the regex portion of the `grep` causes `grep` to return the entire line instead of each matching occurrence.

Comment: `.*` matches as much as possible, always. This is a very common FAQ. Perhaps review the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) before posting more questions.

Comment: Playing around with regexr, I've found that this regex expression will work, but I can't figure out how to implement it with ```grep```:

```\(http:\/\/onsnetwork.org\/kubu4\/.(.*?)\/\)```

Comment: `grep` doesn't support non-greedy regex, or generally the Perl regex extensions which most online regex tools support and seem to take for granted. But a simple negation like `[^ ]`  or, as in the existing answer, `[^()]`, should work fine.

Comment: Also, no need to escape the slashes in `grep`, or generally most sane regex implementations (though there are a few notable exceptions which use slash as the regex delimiter, but then that's a feature of the language, not of its regex implementation. PHP has the questionable honor of requiring slashes for no good reason; but then nobody thought they were sane anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check urls which are *inside* parenthesis:

```
grep -o '(http://onsnetwork.org/kubu4/[^)]*/)' # So, [^)]* and not .*
```

With `.*/`, grep while extract from `(` to the last `/` encountered.